# Android Picasso: Method call should happen from the main thread

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am trying to get info from a server, including photos. I have created a class called `ServerManager`, which allows me to download the desired information. However, I cannot download images with Picasso because I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.`.

This is what I am doing in `ServerManager`:

```
// Check if the photo is already downloaded
if (!checkInternalPhoto(member)) {
    final String outputURL = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + member.photoPath;
    String photoURL = rootURL + "photos/" + member.photoPath;
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(photoURL)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    File file = new File(outputURL);
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outputStream);
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("IOException",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                }
    });
}
```

What can I do?

Edit: I tried to use the code in my MainActivity and I am getting the same error message...

```
 public void downloadPhotos(List<Member> memberList){
    String rootInURL = serverManager.getRootURL();
    String rootOutURL = serverManager.getOutputURL();
    for(int i = 0; i < memberList.size(); i++){
        if(!serverManager.checkInternalPhoto(memberList.get(i))){
            final String outputURL = rootOutURL + memberList.get(i).photoPath;
            String photoURL = rootInURL + "photos/" + memberList.get(i).photoPath;
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(photoURL)
                    .into(new Target() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                            File file = new File(outputURL);
                            try{
                                file.createNewFile();
                                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outputStream);
                                outputStream.flush();
                                outputStream.close();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "YEpa: " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (IOException e){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From where are you calling `downloadPhotos()`. update the answer with the `MainActivity` code

Answer (score 2):

Try this and your error should disappear. This problem always happens when you use it in Unit Android test

> kotlin code

```
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
 }
```

> java code

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't update an ui element from a different thread than the one which created that ui element. On Android that almost always means the main thread.

What you need to do is send back the `photoUrl` String to your activity or fragment on the main thread. The traditional way of doing it is by using a `Handler`. You can read about this more here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: I think i don't understand this...

I just tried to run the code on my main activity and I get the same error message :(
 (I edited the post)

Comment: What calls `downloadPhotos`?